# python dictionary group by , order by and create a new key based on rank

Tags: python

How to apply group by location, order by time and create a new key based on rank in python dictionary

li_input_dict

```
[
{"name":"Alex","location":"US","time":"2020-05-20 10:36:20"},
{"name":"Bob","location":"India","time":"2017-05-20 12:36:20"},
{"name":"Jon","location":"US","time":"2017-05-20 05:36:20"},
{"name":"Kerry","location":"India","time":"2014-05-20 05:36:20"},
{"name":"Mat","location":"US","time":"2013-01-20 05:36:20"},
{"name":"Sazen","location":"India","time":"2013-01-20 05:36:20"}
]
```

output
out is required a new key name as new_name in the dictionary which need to append a number based on data group by location and order by timestamp

```
[
    {"name":"Alex","location":"US","time":"2020-05-20 10:36:20","new_name":"Alex_3"},
    {"name":"Bob","location":"India","time":"2017-05-20 12:36:20","new_name":"Bob_3"},
    {"name":"Jon","location":"US","time":"2017-05-20 05:36:20","new_name":"Jon_2"},
    {"name":"Kerry","location":"India","time":"2014-05-20 05:36:20","new_name":"Kerry_2"},
    {"name":"Mat","location":"US","time":"2013-01-20 05:36:20","new_name":"Mat_1"},
    {"name":"Sazen","location":"India","time":"2013-01-20 05:36:20","new_name":"Suzen_1"}
    ]
```

Edited after Mark comment

I tried to sort by time and order by location by below line but unable to use rank in dictionary ,sorry I am not much expert in python ,can do it in sql.

```
li_input_dict.sort(key=lambda x:time.mktime(time(strptime(x['time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
li_input_dict = sorted(li_input_dict,key =itemgetter('location'))
```

I am not looking the solution in pandas

Comment: You have explained your requirements, but you didn't actually ask a question. What is preventing you from doing this? Which part of this don't you know how to do?

Comment: li_input_dict.sort(key=lambda x:time.mktime(time(strptime(x['time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))     li_input_dict = sorted(li_input_dict,key =itemgetter('location'))      I tried to sort by time like and order by location by above line but unable to use rank in dictionary ,sorry I am not much expert in python ,can do it in sql.

Comment: @Mark I have tried to edit the original post for better clarity.

Comment: Your input and output have different dates. In the first example Bob is `2017-05-20 12:36:20` but in the output Bob is `2013-05-20 12:36:20`. Why did that change?

Comment: what is rank, btw?

Comment: in sql it a window function that assigns a rank/number to each row within a partition of a result set  so if I partition by location and order by time in thus case I can use rank which can be used to create a new key in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a list of dictionaries sorted by location and time. This will put the groups together and within the groups they will be sorted by time:

```
l = [
    {"name":"Alex","location":"US","time":"2020-05-20 10:36:20"},
    {"name":"Bob","location":"India","time":"2017-05-20 12:36:20"},
    {"name":"Jon","location":"US","time":"2017-05-20 05:36:20"},
    {"name":"Kerry","location":"India","time":"2014-05-20 05:36:20"},
    {"name":"Mat","location":"US","time":"2013-01-20 05:36:20"},
    {"name":"Sazen","location":"India","time":"2013-01-20 05:36:20"}
]

l_sort = sorted(l, key=lambda d: (d['location'], d['time']))
```

Now you have a list `l_sort` that looks like:

```
[{'name': 'Sazen', 'location': 'India', 'time': '2013-01-20 05:36:20'},
 {'name': 'Kerry', 'location': 'India', 'time': '2014-05-20 05:36:20'},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'location': 'India', 'time': '2017-05-20 12:36:20'},
 {'name': 'Mat', 'location': 'US', 'time': '2013-01-20 05:36:20'},
 {'name': 'Jon', 'location': 'US', 'time': '2017-05-20 05:36:20'},
 {'name': 'Alex', 'location': 'US', 'time': '2020-05-20 10:36:20'}]
```

Now that everything is in the correct place you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard library to make groups based on location, then for each dict in each group update the dictionary:

```
from itertools import groupby 

# group by location
groups = groupby(l_sort, key=lambda d: d['location'])

# for each location
for k, group in groups:
    # update the dicts with the correct index starting at 1
    for i, d in enumerate(group, 1):
        d['new_name'] = f"{d['name']}_{i}"
```

This will update the dicts in place, so your original list will now have dicts like:

```
[{'name': 'Alex','location': 'US','time': '2020-05-20 10:36:20','new_name': 'Alex_3'},
 {'name': 'Bob','location': 'India','time': '2017-05-20 12:36:20','new_name': 'Bob_3'},
 {'name': 'Jon','location': 'US','time': '2017-05-20 05:36:20','new_name': 'Jon_2'},
 {'name': 'Kerry','location': 'India','time': '2014-05-20 05:36:20','new_name': 'Kerry_2'},
 {'name': 'Mat','location': 'US','time': '2013-01-20 05:36:20','new_name': 'Mat_1'},
 {'name': 'Sazen','location': 'India','time': '2013-01-20 05:36:20','new_name': 'Sazen_1'}]
```

Comment: is there way to append sequence number to new_name on basic of number of groups,lets say if we have 2 groups per location ,first group has total 3 records then append the new_name as original_name_1,original_name_2,original_name_3 but if second group has total 12 records then new_name to be original_name_01,original_name_02,.original_name_03...original_name_12 .its like adding number based on number of records per group ,if group records is less than 10 then original_name_1 ,if records are more than 10 then original_name_01,I tried to len(list(group)) but then I am getting error in enumerator